# support vector machine train caret error kernlab class probability calculations failed; returning NAs

Tags: r, testing, r-caret

i have some data and Y variable is a factor - Good or Bad. I am building a Support vector machine using 'train' method from 'caret' package. Using 'train' function i was able to finalize values of various tuning parameters and got the final Support vector machine . For the test data i can predict the 'class'. But when i try to predict probabilities for test data, i get below error (for example my model tells me that 1st data point in test data has y='good', but i want to know what is the probability of getting 'good' ...generally in case of support vector machine, model will calculate probability of prediction..if Y variable has 2 outcomes then model will predict probability of each outcome. The outcome which has the maximum probability is considered as  the final solution)

```
**Warning message:  
In probFunction(method, modelFit, ppUnk) :  
  kernlab class probability calculations failed; returning NAs**
```

sample code as below

```
library(caret)
trainset <- data.frame( 
     class=factor(c("Good",    "Bad",   "Good", "Good", "Bad",  "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Bad",  "Bad",  "Bad")),
     age=c(67,  22, 49, 45, 53, 35, 53, 35, 61, 28, 25, 24))

testset <- data.frame( 
     class=factor(c("Good",    "Bad",   "Good"  )),
    age=c(64,   23, 50))



library(kernlab)
set.seed(231)

### finding optimal value of a tuning parameter
sigDist <- sigest(class ~ ., data = trainset, frac = 1)
### creating a grid of two tuning parameters, .sigma comes from the earlier line. we are trying to find best value of .C
svmTuneGrid <- data.frame(.sigma = sigDist[1], .C = 2^(-2:7))

set.seed(1056)
svmFit <- train(class ~ .,
                data = trainset,
                method = "svmRadial",
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                tuneGrid = svmTuneGrid,
                trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5))

### svmFit finds the optimal values of tuning parameters and builds the model using the best parameters

### to predict class of test data
predictedClasses <- predict(svmFit, testset )
str(predictedClasses)


### predict probablities but i get an error
predictedProbs <- predict(svmFit, newdata = testset , type = "prob")
head(predictedProbs)
```

*new question below this line: as per below output there are 9 support vectors. how to recognize out of 12 training data points which are those 9?*

```
svmFit$finalModel
```

Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm"

SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
 parameter : cost C = 1

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  0.72640759446315

Number of Support Vectors : 9

Objective Function Value : -5.6994 
Training error : 0.083333

Comment: It's the "caret" package and the "train" function. No code for construction of a test case is included. If you want attention to the question, you should reconsider making the question reproducible (either by using a dataset in the caret-package or by using `dput(head( your_data, 30))` , and you might consider using your caps-key more often where appropriate and less often when not.

Comment: agree with your inputs, I have added the sample code...and tried to modify my capitalization

Comment: I've edited my answer to address your additional questions. For some reason, the model only extracted 8 SVs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the train control statement, you have to specify if you want the class probabilities `classProbs = TRUE` returned.

```
svmFit <- train(class ~ .,
    data = trainset,
    method = "svmRadial",
    preProc = c("center", "scale"),
    tuneGrid = svmTuneGrid,
    trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 5, 
classProbs =  TRUE))

predictedClasses <- predict(svmFit, testset )
predictedProbs <- predict(svmFit, newdata = testset , type = "prob")
```

giving the probabilities of being in the Bad or Good class in the test dataset as:

```
print(predictedProbs)
    Bad      Good
1 0.2302979 0.7697021
2 0.7135050 0.2864950
3 0.2230889 0.7769111
```

#### EDIT

To answer your new question, you can access the position of the support vectors in your original data set with `alphaindex(svmFit$finalModel)` with coefficients `coef(svmFit$finalModel)`.

Comment: if i type in 'svmFit$finalModel'
Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 

SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
 parameter : cost C = 1 

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  0.72640759446315 

Number of Support Vectors : 9 

Objective Function Value : -5.6994 
Training error : 0.083333

Comment: if possible please answer my question. i have added my question below line "new question below this line" in my original question

Comment: thanks...i tired those commands...do they return alpha/weights of data points? i found one more command alphaindex(svmFit$finalModel)..i guess that returns position of data points that are support vectors, am i correct?

Comment: You are correct - alphaindex returns the position of data points used as support vectors, and coef returns the signed weights, where the sign is positive for sv belonging to the first group and negative belonging to the second.

Comment: one more thing svmFit$finalModel command output says that "SV type: C-svc (classification) parameter : cost C = 1". does that mean the maximum weight that any support vector will have is 1? i tested it on our data and i didnt see any weight >1, but would like to get your nod..

Comment: I had to look it up, but yes, in soft-margin SVM, the weights are constrained to be greater or equal to 0 and less than or equal to C. There's a good reference by Tristan Fletcher at http://www.tristanfletcher.co.uk/SVM%20Explained.pdf

Comment: that pdf is very good, thanks...one more question: it is regarding Neural networks. I have built a neural network model oon the same data and i want to find out weights that have beeen used inside each hidden node. based upon page http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/nnet/nnet i tried neuralnetobject$finalModel$wts and i also tried wts(neuralnetobject$finalModel) but i didnt get any weights:(

Comment: @user2543622: You should probably post that as a new question for Crossvalidated since I'm not entirely familiar with neural networks an d chances are you will get better responses.

Comment: already posted it 2 days back -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156349/r-language-how-to-access-wts-of-a-class-objects-nnet ...havent got any respnse yet :(

Comment: @user2543622: Stackoverflow is for programming-specific problems and require reproducible problems. Your question on neural networks did not provide any sample code or sample data so that's probably why you didn't get a response.  Cross-validated is a statistics-based Q&A site that is better suited for your question on nn. http://stats.stackexchange.com